# MS Word: Cannot continue in LTR language after Footnote on an RTL word in a mostly LTR document

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

I'm trying to use MS Word to type a document that involves both English (LTR) and Hebrew (RTL) text.

If a document starts, for example, with:

> Hello World שלום עולם

Note that the left-most "ם" is the last letter, as Hebrew is an RTL language.  If a footnote is placed just after that last letter, it then becomes IMPOSSIBLE to type English on the right side of the Hebrew in the main body text - all english text will go on the left of the Hebrew.

Three is typed after the two ("שנים") and the footnote:
[image: One, Two, Three, typed, with the middle word in Hebrew and footnoted.]

Is this a bug?  How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem but I was trying to insert an English word into an Arabic text.

Since it was an LTR language inside an RTL language, the steps mentioned in the first answer in the following link worked excellently for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613613/why-words-are-shuffled-when-i-insert-english-words-in-any-arabic-urdu-persian-te

Since it's the other way around for you, let me reorganize the steps:

1. Finish typing the English word and add a space after it.
2. Insert* special character named: "left to right mark"; it indicates that the block of text before it is LTR.

*Insert it in Word by going to Insert -> Symbol -> More Symbols -> Special characters [scroll down], you will find "left to right mark" there, click on it and insert it. Nothing will appear on the screen because it's a non-printing character, so it's normal if you felt like nothing happened.

3. Insert special character "Right to Left Embedding" [found in the same place]. It will indicate that a Right to Left block will now be written.
4. Add another space [to separate the word from the LTR text that will continue later].
5. Change your keyboard to Hebrew and write the Hebrew [or any RTL word].
6. Insert special character "Pop Directional Formatting" to end the effect of the "Left to Right Embedding" character you inserted earlier.
7. Change the Keyboard and continue writing in English.

   Make sure that when you are writing an English paragraph, the LTR option in the ribbon is selected [which usually is the case]. It is the one that is NOT circled in red in the following figure:

[image: I can't post an image yet so click on link to see it]

If you are doing it the other way around, that is, writing an English word in a Hebrew paragraph, make sure that RTL option [circled in red] is selected, and then follow the steps in the original link I provided [the link mentions the code of the special characters instead of the name, google the codes and you will know what is the name of the character].

If you forgot to select the RTL paragraph option [in the case you were entering an English word in Hebrew paragraph], the steps won't work at all. Selecting the direction of the paragraph [circled in green] is not enough in RTL case.

To know more about what each of these special characters does, and what it means to mark your paragraph as LTR or RTL, see the following link:
http://dotancohen.com/howto/rtl_right_to_left.html#Directionality

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a contradiction in the requirements, and Word chose the other way out of it (than the one you would have wanted.

When you want to type something *after* (= to the right of) the Hebrew text, it would be effectively *before* that text, as that text is RTL. But if it is *before* that text, it ends up where it does now *before* it (where you don't want it).

Mixing RTL and LTR in one line cannot really work well, as there are often conceptual contradictions between the two writing styles.

I think it should be easy to work around by typing the English before and after texts first, and then pasting the Hebrew piece into the middle of it.

Basically, the insertion mark takes on a direction that you might or might not want, and it can't know that. It might also work to copy an LTR (English) *blank*, and past it to the right of the Hebrew (RTL) text, and then the insertion mark would keep the LTR setting when you click behind it.

Comment: It works perfectly fine in Google Docs.